# How to random select 3 element without repeating?

Tags: flutter, dart

## **Random 3 Element with repeating**

How to random select 3  element without repeating?

```
List<Question> imageList = [
    Question(
      index: 1,
      image: 'assets/images/1.png',
    ),
    Question(
      index: 2,
      image: 'assets/images/2.png',
    ),
    Question(
      index: 3,
      image: 'assets/images/3.png',
    ),
    Question(
      index: 4,
      image: 'assets/images/4.png',
    ),
    Question(
      index: 5,
      image: 'assets/images/5.png',
    ),
    
  ];
```

1. This is Element List

```
getRandom =
          List<Question>.generate(3, (_) => imageList[random.nextInt(imageList.length)]);
```

2. This is Random Function with repeating.

Comment: If you want three random elements without repeating, use [`List.shuffle`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/shuffle.html) and then select three elements.  If you want three random elements *with* repeats, then use [`Random.nextInt`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-math/Random/nextInt.html) to randomly select elements.

Comment: If you use the collection package (https://pub.dev/packages/collection) there is an extension method called `sample` (https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableExtension/sample.html) that will select x random elements from a collection. Using `sample` you can simply write `getRandom = imageList.sample(3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I solved this problem

Initialized with variable

```
List<Question> getRandom = [];
late Question correctElement;
Random random = Random();
```

Init State for first time run

```
@override
  void initState() {
    setRandom();
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('getRandomNum is $getRandom & correctElement is $correctElement');
    }
    super.initState();
  }
```

Used do while loop to unrepeate

```
Question shaffel() {
    return imageList[random.nextInt(imageList.length)];
  }

  setRandom() {
    getRandom.clear();
    do {
      Question data = shaffel();
      if (getRandom.isEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          getRandom.add(data);
        });
      } else if (getRandom.contains(data)) {
      } else {
        setState(() {
          getRandom.add(data);
        });
      }
    } while (getRandom.length != 3);
    correctElement = getRandom[random.nextInt(getRandom.length)];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define an `extension` on `List<T>` so you can reuse it on all types of `List`:

```dart
List<String> alphabets = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];

extension XList<T> on List<T> {
  List<T> takeRandom(int n) {
    return ([...this]..shuffle()).take(n).toList();
  }
}

void main() {
  print(alphabets.takeRandom(3));
  print(alphabets.takeRandom(5));
  print(alphabets.takeRandom(7));
}
```

## Console log

```
[B, S, G]
[P, M, F, Q, K]
[U, M, R, C, Z, D, G]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the list count;

```
int total = imageList.length;
```

create index list numbers;

```
var listindex = List<int>.generate(total, (i) => i++);
```

shuffle list;

```
listindex .shuffle();
//result
[3, 6, 2, 0, 9, 1, 5, 7, 8, 4]
```

and get data from first 3 index list.

imageList[3].image

imageList[6].image

imageList[2].image